# AIF360 reweighing technique example errors

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, aif360

I was trying to run the aif360 reweighing technique from the github link (https://github.com/Trusted-AI/AIF360/blob/master/examples/demo_reweighing_preproc.ipynb). Even though I downloaded all the right files per the instruction. I was unable to successfully run it all because of the error :

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
30 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
31
---> 32 from common_utils import compute_metrics

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common_utils'

Unless I found this module and run it successfully, I won't be able to calculate the metrics. Has anybody encountered this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from common_utils import compute_metrics` is a local import there. `common_utils.py` is avilable [here](https://github.com/Trusted-AI/AIF360/blob/master/examples/common_utils.py). You just need to download and copy it to the same directory where your `demo_reweighing_preproc.ipynb` notebook file is.